# Change height of iframe on slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currenty have a menu in the middle of the screen, its defaulted to "show".

Under this I have an iframe which is used to fill the remaining space:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var main_height = ($(document).height() - 85 - 230 - 40);
    $(".main").css('height', main_height);
});
</script>
```

(Where 85 - 230 - 40 are others DIVs taking up place). So far so good.

However when I want to SLIDETOGGLE the middle_menu I want the iFrame to update its height and add 230px to it (And remove 230px again when I toggle middle_menu on). Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".middle_toggle").click(function () { 
    $(".middle").slideToggle(20, function() {                  
    $(".colapse_bar").toggleClass('middle_colapsed');
    $("#colapse_icon").toggleClass("colapse_fix colapse_fix2"); 

    });     
}); 
</script>
```

How ever I do this. It just doesnt work! Need help, thanks :)

Comment: This is unclear? `slideToggle` does some specific, it slides and then toggles the element, hiding or showing it. If you just want to change the height, you'd use `animate()` to do that.

Comment: I want the middle_menu to slidetoggle away. But when it does, it now leaves a 230px hole at the bottom of the screen. So I want the iFrame to add 230px to itself depenings if the middle_menu is toggled or not.

Comment: Then animate the height of the iframe at the same time the element is being hidden

Comment: Which is what im asking. How do I do it? Since Ive tried to do it and I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it real ugly. But it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



        $(".middle_toggle").click(function () {


        $(".middle").slideToggle(20, function() {                  
        $(".colapse_bar").toggleClass('middle_colapsed');
        $("#colapse_icon").toggleClass("colapse_fix colapse_fix2");

        if ($('.middle').is(":hidden")) {   
        var main_height2 = ($(document).height() - 125);
        $(".main").css('height', main_height2);
        }


        if ($('.middle').is(":visible")) {  
        var main_height2 = ($(document).height() - 355);
        $(".main").css('height', main_height2);
        }

        }); 







    }); 
    </script>
```